# Need to change storage db path in mongo secondary node of replica set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

We have 3 members replica set of mongo db (MongoDB server version: 4.2.9). one of the member (secondary) is running on default storage db path and this storage getting nearly full. We need to change path of that specific secondary node of 3-member replica set. I am new to mongodb. I need your expertise to accomplish this task.

MongoDB server version: 4.2.9
OS Version: CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core).

Regards,

Comment: Maybe [Perform Maintenance on Replicaset Members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### Option 1: ( preserving the current already synced data )

1. Stop the mongod service:

   ```
   mongo --host xxxx --port yyyy  
   use admin
   db.shutdownServer()
   ```
2. Copy the data from old location to the new location:

   ```
   cp -R /oldPath/ /newPath/
   ```
3. Change in the /etc/mongodb.conf the dbPath to point to the new location.
4. Start the mongodb service.

---

### Option 2) Init sync the member from the other members.

Same like option 1) , just ommit the point 2) just you will need to wait abit until the member init sync ( copy the data ) from the other members , it depends on data size and compression.

---

### Option 3) Better high availability:

1. From the PRIMARY member add another member on that will use the new path:

   ```
   rs.add("newMember:XXXX")
   ```
2. Wait until the new member init sync.
3. Remove the old SECONDARY member:

   ```
   rs.remove("oldMember:YYYY")
   ```
4. Clean the old files and configuration.
   ( small disadvantage with this option that you will need to change the port for the new member if on the same host  )

Option 2) seems best suitable for your case ...

Comment: Thanks for the solutions offered. One more question about using option# 2. Whether init.sync process will start automatically to sync or we have to start it by any mean. If we have to start init.sync manually by setting up any parameter or executing any command, kindly share with us the steps/doc.

Comment: mongo will identify  that the data folder is empty and will start the init process automatically  so you dont need to do anything to trigger the process ... , you can watch the replicaSet status with rs.status() from time to time to see when the member will become SECONDARY again ...

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution you've offered is working fine except one thing. When we applied the solution offered in option#2, the PRIMARY role was assigned to remaining SECONDARY while the PRIMARY became SECONDARY. Can you please explain it for us.

Comment: Ahh maybe missed to mention that is safer before stopping PRIMARY members to switch them to SECONDARY with rs.stepDown() to avoid election during the shutdown  ,  so if your member was PRIMARY when you stop it  the other members will trigger election process and will vote for new PRIMARY ( the member accepting the writes) , even is best if you switch the member to HIDDEN so the application to not see it at all during the maintenance activity ... , but in general what you did is fine ...